# Metal [[early_fragment_tests]] on frag shader works on Mac OSX, but not iOS

Tags: ios, fragment-shader, metal

With Metal, does it matter whether or not I have anything attached to the color targets in order to use early_fragment_tests on iOS?  When I add early_fragment_tests to my frag shader, then it seems as though all my fragments are rejected on iOS.  It works properly on OS X.  So far the only thing I can think of is that it might have to do with the fact that I don't have any color targets attached. Would that matter?  I'm writing to offscreen buffers instead.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Please stop tagging your Metal questions with OpenGL unless GL is actually *relevant* to your question. This question about the behavior of Metal has nothing to do with GL.

Comment: Sorry, I won't do that anymore.

Comment: How are the fragment tests (depth, stencil) actually configured? Are you sure the inputs are well defined? For example, what's the load action for the depth and/or stencil attachments?